# Accessing an IIS Website from a mobile phone that is connected via usb cable directly with the windows machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, mobile

You may find this question very odd but these days we have all sorts of windows and mobile phone apps. Although googling it didn't help but I thought may be someone somewhere knows the answer.

Is it possible to access an IIS hosted website on a mobile phone. Mobile phone is connected to the windows machine via usb cable. If it is possible then what is the procedure please.

IIS Website is written in asp.net mvc 4 razor with c#.
Unfortunately the network does not have a wifi so connecting to the windows machine via wifi is out of the question.
I am administrator of my windows machine.
At the moment, it is also not possible to host the website on the server and make it available over the internet.
My phone is latest android.

In simple words, I have a website that is hosted on IIS and the phone is connected to the machine via usb and I want to browse the website from my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas from the top of my head:

- If your mobile phone has internet access and you can access your network router (or you can ask your admin to do this for you) than you could just simply forward a port to your PC and connect from internet to your router with appropriate port. Please look into your router manual for more details
- You can also buy cheap usb wifi key that you can use with your PC as set up direct connection with your phone
- Depending on your mobile phone OS you can actually share internet connection (so probably at the same time give your phone access to your local PC) by using 3rd party software and some hacks - this is one for Android but requires rooted OS http://www.howtogeek.com/117118/how-to-connect-your-android-to-your-pcs-internet-connection-over-usb/

Good luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry cant give you a vote up. I dont have enough reputation points.

Comment: No problem, I hope I have helped you :-)